# Did not get the required output when using pxssh module

Tags: python, ssh

I have written the below program to ssh access into the windows server running on vmware and get the ssh logs details:

```
import pxssh

import getpass

s = pxssh.pxssh()

hostname = '****'

username = '****'

password = getpass.getpass("Enter the password \n")

s.login (hostname,username,password)

s.sendline ('cd\;cd Program Files;type freeSSHdfreesshd.log') 

s.prompt()

print s.before
```

When I executed the above scripts I get below error messages:

Anyone has any idea what change is required to remove this error and get the required output?

Comment: sry for not mentioning the error i got it,when i executed the code..error given below

Comment: File "SSHaccess.py", line 15, in <module>
s.login (hostname,username,password)
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/pexpect/pxssh.py", line 317, in login
    
pexpect.pxssh.ExceptionPxssh: could not synchronize with original prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with pxssh,

but perhaps it would work better with [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/)

```
import paramiko
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(server, username=user,password=password)
cmd='cd \;cd "Program Files";type freeSSHdfreesshd.log'
stdin, stdout, stderr =ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
ssh_client.close()
```

Comment: .i have modified the program to use Paramiko module.. kindly have a look in below program which i tried..it looks like the module doesn read the commants as per our requirement..

Comment: Try and type the command yourself in the terminal, I highly doubt `cd Program Files` would work

Answer (score 0):

```
import paramiko

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(server, username=username,password=password)

cmd='cd\;cd Program Files;type freeSSHdfreesshd.log'
stdin, stdout, stderr =ssh_client.exec_command(cmd)
output=stdout.readlines()

print output

ssh_client.close()
```

Comment: gives the error "[u'Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.\r\n']"